# Spring Getting Started Guide "Accessing JPA Data with REST" not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, spring-web

I'm learning Spring using the Getting Started Guides. Right now I'm trying to complete "Accessing JPA Data with REST" guide but my code didn't work, so I tried the "complete" version, and it doesn't work too. So far everytime I import content using Spring Tool Suite (STS), the "complete" version executes as expected, according to the description in the guides, but it's not happening right now.

The guide instructs me to run the Project as a "Spring Boot App", then to execute a curl command to see the top level service:

Command:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "people" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  }
}
```

My output:

```
{"timestamp":1472183640477,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/"}
```

I'm on machine with Windows 10 Pro x64, Java 1.8.0_102, STS version 3.8.1.RELEASE, build id 201607290850 and using Spring Boot version 1.4.0.RELEASE. I am using Maven to build inside STS.

The code is very simple, only three classes, and I haven't changed anything. You can check the code [here on github](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-rest/tree/master/complete). The Spring Guide is [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/).

Here's my console output, I think I may be missing some important message and it would help to identify the problem:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.0.RELEASE)

2016-08-26 00:53:49.504  INFO 3508 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on DESKTOP-1MI7COJ with PID 3508 (C:\Users\Alisson\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.1.RELEASE\gs-accessing-data-rest-complete\target\classes started by Alisson in C:\Users\Alisson\Documents\workspace-sts-3.8.1.RELEASE\gs-accessing-data-rest-complete)
2016-08-26 00:53:49.516  INFO 3508 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-26 00:53:49.672  INFO 3508 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@9597028: startup date [Fri Aug 26 00:53:49 BRT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-26 00:53:53.143  INFO 3508 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6c160edf] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-26 00:53:54.229  INFO 3508 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-08-26 00:53:54.252  INFO 3508 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-08-26 00:53:54.254  INFO 3508 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
2016-08-26 00:53:54.520  INFO 3508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-08-26 00:53:54.521  INFO 3508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4857 ms
2016-08-26 00:53:54.886  INFO 3508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-08-26 00:53:54.898  INFO 3508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-26 00:53:54.910  INFO 3508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-26 00:53:54.910  INFO 3508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-26 00:53:54.910  INFO 3508 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-26 00:53:55.721  INFO 3508 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-08-26 00:53:55.756  INFO 3508 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-08-26 00:53:55.952  INFO 3508 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.9.Final}
2016-08-26 00:53:55.956  INFO 3508 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-08-26 00:53:55.959  INFO 3508 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-08-26 00:53:56.029  INFO 3508 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-08-26 00:53:56.410  INFO 3508 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2016-08-26 00:53:57.198  INFO 3508 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2016-08-26 00:53:57.214  INFO 3508 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2016-08-26 00:53:57.296  INFO 3508 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-08-26 00:53:58.616  INFO 3508 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@9597028: startup date [Fri Aug 26 00:53:49 BRT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-26 00:53:58.798  INFO 3508 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-08-26 00:53:58.800  INFO 3508 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-08-26 00:53:58.869  INFO 3508 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-26 00:53:58.870  INFO 3508 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-26 00:53:59.068  INFO 3508 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-26 00:53:59.681  INFO 3508 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-08-26 00:53:59.804  INFO 3508 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-08-26 00:53:59.814  INFO 3508 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 11.173 seconds (JVM running for 11.996)
2016-08-26 00:54:00.293  INFO 3508 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-08-26 00:54:00.293  INFO 3508 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-08-26 00:54:00.346  INFO 3508 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 53 ms
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Link to your project or paste your code

Comment: @hd1 thanks, I just added a link to the source code on github (https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-rest/tree/master/complete). As I said, I didn't change anything, just ran it as a Spring Boot App.

Comment: Very weird, this example is working as expected for me. Does it throw any exception when you call the API?

Comment: @g00glen00b it doesn't throw any exception, I just don't get the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Look at this part :

```
--- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@9597028: startup date [Fri Aug 26 00:53:49 BRT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
--- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
--- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
--- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
--- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
--- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

There are only a few URL mappings, and none points to */people*, so no wonder you get a 404 error.

I just git-cloned the project, build it and run it with NetBeans under Windows. here is the console output (I skipped a few lines due to StackOverflow 30k characters limit):

```
--- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on DSI0130013FB with PID 11112 (C:\Users\mtarin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gs-accessing-data-rest\complete\target\classes started by mtarin in C:\Users\mtarin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\gs-accessing-data-rest\complete)
--- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
--- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3d51f06e: startup date [Fri Aug 26 09:57:06 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$455ad2f4] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.data.rest-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestProperties' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$836923e6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.jackson-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e51fa8d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'standardJacksonObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration$StandardJackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$533b149e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$82f9f014] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jsonComponentModule' of type [class org.springframework.boot.jackson.JsonComponentModule] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataJacksonConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataJacksonConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e0146c8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonGeoModule' of type [class org.springframework.data.geo.GeoModule] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' of type [class org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'springBootRepositoryRestConfigurer' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.SpringBootRepositoryRestConfigurer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'defaultRelProvider' of type [class org.springframework.hateoas.core.EvoInflectorRelProvider] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'annotationRelProvider' of type [class org.springframework.hateoas.core.AnnotationRelProvider] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '(inner bean)#3291b443' of type [class org.springframework.plugin.core.support.PluginRegistryFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '(inner bean)#3291b443' of type [class org.springframework.plugin.core.OrderAwarePluginRegistry] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '_relProvider' of type [class org.springframework.hateoas.core.DelegatingRelProvider] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cb569c14] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
--- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
(...)
--- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
--- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
--- [           main] o.s.b.f.config.PropertiesFactoryBean     : Loading properties file from class path resource [rest-default-messages.properties]
--- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3d51f06e: startup date [Fri Aug 26 09:57:06 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
--- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
--- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
--- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
--- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
--- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in repositoryRestExceptionHandler
--- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerAdapter   : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3d51f06e: startup date [Fri Aug 26 09:57:06 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryLinksResource> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.listRepositories()
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.optionsForRepositories()
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/ || ],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryController.headForRepositories()
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<?>> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PUT],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.putItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getCollectionResourceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}],methods=[POST],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.optionsForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.headForItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[PATCH],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.patchItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResource,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag,java.lang.String) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.deleteItemResource(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.ETag) throws org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ResourceNotFoundException,org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReferenceCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler) throws java.lang.Exception
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}],methods=[PATCH || PUT || POST],consumes=[application/json || application/x-spring-data-compact+json || text/uri-list],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<? extends org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.createPropertyReference(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<java.lang.Object>,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/{id}/{property}/{propertyId}],methods=[DELETE],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.deletePropertyReferenceId(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.io.Serializable,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,java.lang.String)
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchesResource org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.listSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[HEAD],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.headForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/hal+json || application/json || application/*+json;charset=UTF-8]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.optionsForSearches(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/{repository}/search/{search}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/x-spring-data-compact+json]}" onto public org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearchCompact(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation,org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.DefaultedPageable,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler)
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/alps+json || */*]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.descriptor(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[OPTIONS],produces=[application/alps+json]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsController.alpsOptions()
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[OPTIONS]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.profileOptions()
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile],methods=[GET]}" onto org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.ProfileController.listAllFormsOfMetadata()
--- [           main] o.s.d.r.w.BasePathAwareHandlerMapping    : Mapped "{[/profile/{repository}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/schema+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.JsonSchema> org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySchemaController.schema(org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RootResourceInformation)
--- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in repositoryRestExceptionHandler
--- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
--- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
--- [           main] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 27.932 seconds (JVM running for 29.637)
--- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
--- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
--- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 19 ms
```

You can see there are many mappings (all the *Mapped "{[/{repository}/* lines) than what you got.

I get the same result if I build and run the project manually using:

```
mvn clean package
java -jar target\target\gs-accessing-data-rest-0.1.0.jar
```

Does STS show the commands it uses?

Comment: I had no previous experience with Maven so it took me a while to reproduce your steps. After setting up my enverionment for correctly for Maven, I was able see this message: "[WARNING] error reading spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)". I deleted the jar and then executed "mvn clean package" and now it's working, from Maven and from STS.

Answer (score 0):

I executed the build from Maven and this time it showed a message that a jar file was corrupted:

```
[WARNING] error reading  C:\Users\Alisson\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-rest-webmvc\2.5.2.RELEASE\spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

I deleted the "spring-data-rest-webmvc" folder and, next time I ran the build, Maven downloaded the correct jar again. Now it works from command line and inside STS too.

STS wasn't showing this error message and I had tried "Update Project... / Force Update of Snapshots/Releases", so I guess the best option is to always use Maven to build instead of "Run as Spring Boot App".